# How can I get the end row of my sheet (not the last row with data) in Google Sheets Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, row

I would like to know how can I get the end row of my sheet (not the last row with data). Is there a simple code to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

You can use `getMaxRows()` to get the end row number.

**Sample:**

[image]

[image]

**Reference:**

[getMaxRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getMaxRows())

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people want to do this because they don't want to have to scroll down past all of their data so the typical approach is something like this:

```
function getFirstRowAfterAllData0() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1, 1).activate();
}
```

But if sh.getLastRow() equals sh.getMaxRows() then this won't work because the script can't go to a line that doesn't exist and so you'll find that this approach will work in that situation also.  It adds another row to the bottom when there aren't any available rows after your data.

```
function getFirstRowAfterAllData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (sh.getLastRow() < sh.getMaxRows()) {
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1, 1).activate();
  } else {
    sh.insertRowAfter(sh.getLastRow());
    sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1, 1).activate();
  }
}
```